# Explain the GetMetadata parameters

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, librdkafka

As the [documentation](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/kafka/adminapi.go#L858) of function `GetMetaData`:

```
// GetMetadata queries broker for cluster and topic metadata.
// If topic is non-nil only information about that topic is returned, else if
// allTopics is false only information about locally used topics is returned,
// else information about all topics is returned.
// GetMetadata is equivalent to listTopics, describeTopics and describeCluster in the Java API.
func (a *AdminClient) GetMetadata(topic *string, allTopics bool, timeoutMs int) (*Metadata, error) {
    return getMetadata(a, topic, allTopics, timeoutMs)
}
```

So I guess if the topic is non-nil, the result always returns only the specific topic information. However, when I try to test, I see the very strange result.

Let say I I already have a Kafka topic. Then I call the method `GetMetadata` as the below code:

```
topic := "sample_topic"
admin.GetMetadata(nil, false, timeout)
admin.GetMetadata(nil, true, timeout)
admin.GetMetadata(&topic, false, timeout)
admin.GetMetadata(&topic, true, timeout)
```

Only `admin.GetMetadata(&topic, false, timeout)` returns the topic information. All other cases return all topics information.

However, when testing on a non-exist topic in the cluster, only the call `admin.GetMetadata(&topic, false, timeout)` will yield the error.

```
data, err := admin.GetMetadata(&topic, false, admin.timeOutMs())
fmt.Println(data.Topics[topic]) //   Broker: Unknown topic or partition
```

When re-order the code, the result also changes.

I read the source code and I see that it uses some functions from `librdkafka` such as `rd_kafka_metadata` or `_getMetadata_broker_element`. But it is hard for me to understand those functions.

I tested on the Kafka cluster with 3 brokers. Please explain for me what is the logic behind.